# TB Megamenu - How can I reuse a menu with different megamenu configuration?

Tags: routes

I have a Drupal core menu setup for my main menu that has > 50 links setup.  I've also got TB Megamenu configured for that menu to show the menus with pictures, etc.

Now I have a case in which I want to show the same menu content, but configured differently (to shown only standard flyouts with no images) on all pages but the home page.

I haven't been able to find a way to do this without duplicating the main menu link by link (which I obviously don't find sustainable).

Can anyone think of a way I could accomplish this?

(Note that I did try the Context module, which is great, but is not really suited for this purpose).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Superfish](https://drupal.org/project/superfish) module and reuse same main menu . All you need to do is configure super fish menu block with main menu.

Project page says

"Multi-column sub-menus. (Megamenus)
Easing effects with the jQuery Easing plug-in, and many more...."

Comment: Thanks, that's a great idea.  Didn't realize Superfish had that ability.

Answer (score 0):

While the [project page](https://drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu) states this is an upcoming feature:

> Multi instances of one Drupal core menu for different
>   styles/appearance

Meanwhile you can hide (css) or better, unset (custom module) the images for particular pages.